(Python) Issue while trying to deploy a branch in Heroku -Push fails due to NLTK file-
I'm trying to deploy a branch containing FastAPI-wrapped Python endpoints. I'm getting a build error (below), which is causing the branch deployment to fail. I've got nltk==3.8.1 in my requirements.txt, and my nltk.txt is empty because so far in localhost I was able to run successfully with just my pip dependencies installed. It's because of Heroku that I'm adding the nltk.txt to essentially get my code deployed. I don't know what nltk dependencies are trying to be used, that I'd have to import. Any thoughts?
-----> Downloading NLTK packages: 
<frozen runpy>:128: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
       NLTK Downloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2554, in <module>
           d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    downloader.download(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 763, in download
    self._interactive_download()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 1117, in _interactive_download
    DownloaderShell(self).run()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 1141, in run
    user_input = input("Downloader> ").strip()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
       Downloader> -----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
 !     Compiled slug size: 2.7G is too large (max is 500M).
 !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
 !     Push failed


"Compiled slug size: 2.7G is too large (max is 500M)"—your app is way too big to deploy to Heroku. Either pare it down significantly or choose a different host.
